# Get list of bounced emails, Mandrill

Tags: c#, email, mandrill

Im trying to make a quick program that will show the user a list of emails sent through Mandrill that bounced.

This program will NOT be sending the mail, so I need to extract a list instead of getting a notification back after the message was sent.

Currently I am using the export API https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/exports/activity.json to get a list of all bounced emails. The only issue with this is that an export can take 2+ hours just for the past 14 days, and filtered on only bounced emails. This is not acceptable to the end user. A small few minute wait would be ok.

So, is there any other way to get a list of bounced emails? Or is there a way to make sure the export can be completed in a timely manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/search.json

```
{
"key":"htha8888888",  
"query": "state:bounced",  
 "limit": 1000
}
```

The problem with this query is that there is a max of 1000 messages that can be returned, so you will have to do some paging based on time by sizing your time window accordingly, in your search query `"query": "state:bounced AND ts:[START_TIME TO STOP_TIME]"` (note that start and stop times are epoch time in seconds)

Search queries also have lag, there is no SLA on the time. In my experience, I have gotten results no later than 3 hours.If you need immediate notification, I would recommend webhooks, if it is feasible to open your firewall, and let mandrill send updates to your webhook.

Comment: I just found this as well, didn't realize you could query for just bounced emails with this. We shouldn't have the email limit issue. As we are using a lot of sub accounts and i believe it is possible to filter on those as well. its mainly for our stores that want to check their last monthly statements to see which ones didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would configure a Webhook https://mandrillapp.com/settings/webhooks which subscribes to the "Message is bounced" event.

When a mail bounces, Mandrill will post to your defined URL with some JSON which you will need to parse, and log.

Here is the format for the JSON data: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583307-Message-Event-Webhook-format

This will give you near real time tracking of bounces.

Comment: Thanks, seems like web hooks are probably our last choice if we absolutely have to. Firewalls are a pain here...